# Does R have something equivalent to reduce() in Python?

Tags: r, functional-programming, reduce

That is : "Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value. "

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, it's called `Reduce`.

An example:

```
Reduce(paste, LETTERS[1:5])
[1] "A B C D E"

Reduce(sum, 1:5)
[1] 15

#List arguments work the same
Reduce(sum, list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
[1] 15
```

For more information about functional programming in R see the help file for `?funprog`, an alias for `?Reduce`

Comment: +1 for making me spit coffee out my nose after reading the first line.

Comment: @John All in a day's work... Top of the morning, to you, too!

Comment: `Reduce("+",1:5)` is slightly clearer that its working on a function of 2 arguments.

Comment: just a note on `"+"` vs `sum`:`Reduce(sum, list(c(1,2), c(3,4))) = 10`, while `Reduce("+", list(c(1,2), c(3,4))) = c(4,6)`

Comment: Why is it upper Case?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/funprog.html