# How to loop over list of list and access a row by name using R (preferably efficient)?

Tags: r, performance, list, dataframe

This is probably a newbie question:

I have an array (let us call it **a**) each each element of which look like this:

```
structure(list(rs6838241 = structure(list(Results = structure(c(-0.02015,
0.022242, -0.0111580707, 0.0028333, 0.01067,-2.01730, NA, 0.1704, 0.133291277489982,
0.6855, 0.32983, 0.4598227, 6.764345237e-05, 0.31353), .Dim = c(7L, 2L), 
.Dimnames = list(c("FVCpp_utah", "FEV1pp_utah",
"WallAreaPct_seg","Vida_15perc_Exp","pctEmph_Slicer", 
"FEV1_FVC_utah", "JointModel"), c("beta","pvalue"))), 
nobs = 1112L), .Names = c("Results", "nobs"))), .Names = "rs6838241")
```

I would like to find the element with smallest p-value.

I did something like this:

```
m <- 1000
for (i in 1:1000){
  m <- min(m, (a[i]$'Results')['JointModel','pvalue'])
}
```

But it does not do anything!! I am confused why I cannot do this:

```
> (a[1])$'Results'
  NULL
```

while this works?

```
> a$'rs13125929'$'Results'
[SNIPPED]
```

why this one does not work?

```
> s<-'rs13125929'
> (a[s])$'Results'
NULL
```

Is there anyway to find the lowest p-value without looping?

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need parentheses in constructions like: `(a[s])$'Results'`.

Comment: Read `?Extract` or `help("[")`.  On lists, `[` returns a list while `[[` returns the vector you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
min(sapply(a, function(x) x$Results['JointModel','pvalue']))
```

To find the index of the list element with minimum pvalue, use `which.min` instead of `min`.

Comment: it seems to me that sapply is still like a foor-loop and very slow. Isn't it?

Comment: @user2631524 How large is your list? Replicating `a` a million times I get an object of size 1.5 gigabytes and `system.time(min(sapply(...)))` is 7.76 sec.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`Reduce`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) instead of the loop for `min` (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413819/does-r-has-something-equivalent-to-reduce-in-python))
2. use `a[[1]]$'Results'` (note double braces)

Comment: could you please explain how you use "Reduce" ? for loop with "[[" is very slow.

Comment: see linked man page and another SO question for many examples